# Vanilla JS based Ethereum competitor - is there anything out there?

Tags: javascript, ethereum

I'm wondering if there is any serious competitor to Ethereum that's a little easier to use - meaning you don't have to learn yet another programming language (like solidity for ETH) if you know javascript already. The idea is great, but I'd be really interested in an alternative that I can use straight away with vanilla js.
Any ideas?

Comment: I know there are some options for ethereum too: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/javascript/
but I'm rather looking for a native js smart contract blockchain

Comment: Not sure this is the correct place for your question, but lisk is similar but using javascript:
https://lisk.io/

Comment: thanks, I will check it out! I don't really know where else would I ask a question like this and expect an answer

Comment: See, even us minded programmers get confused, the deeper you go the deeper you will face the unthinkable. Also currently the fee for a transaction is over $40. This is not a trading advice but that stuff is going to under a dollar soon.

Comment: @NVRM haha, yes, its a little mind bending, I wouldn't say I understand the whole thing fully but a straight-forward and easy to use solution is yet to emerge - or maybe lisk.io will, time will tell

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can write smart contracts in any programming language as long as you can compile down to virtual machine code.

In the practice, you cannot write smart contracts in JavaScript, because language run-time features make it unsuitable for the task. Because JavaScript is unsuitable for the task in the first place, no one is going to give you tools to write contracts in JavaScript. Writing smart contracts is vastly different from web programming. [You need to understand that there is a long multi-year road of learning for you](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1344610584864677890) regardless of what you do.

The closest thing you get: [NEAR protocol](https://near.org/) supports [AssemblyScript](https://docs.near.org/docs/roles/developer/contracts/assemblyscript) that is a derivate of TypeScript.

Comment: wouldn't that work with xmlhttprequest / ajax?

Comment: Smart contracts cannot call external resources on any blockchain, because doing so would make the blockchain non-determistic and it would fail.

Comment: I'm obviously no expert in the field, but it's an interesting topic.
 
I've seen a few tutorials (blockchain coded in js) - would that be possible to extend such chains functionality to handle their own implementation of smart contracts in determistic way?

Comment: You are asking antigravity.